# Comparing two lists of values of different lengths

Tags: r

I have a long list of random numbers between 1 and 100, and i would like to count how many of them are larger than 10,20,30 etc

```
x <- c(sample(1:100, 500, replace = T))
y <- seq(0,100, by = 10)
```

I am looking for this to return an output such as;

| Total | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Count | 7 | 13 | 17 | 28 | 42 |

Where Count is the number of x Values that are larger than Total (each y value )

So far, I have tried

```
Count = ifelse(x > y, 1, 0)
```

However this returns a list of Binary 1,0 returns for each of the 500 values of X

I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **base R** this is one approach

```
rbind(Total = y, Count = rowSums(sapply(x, ">", y)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
Total    0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80    90   100
Count  500  444  381  329  279  241  198  150  104    52     0
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer asummes your looking for intervals not for cummulative sum of numbers greater than a threshold given your count.

`cut` + `table` are useful here:

```
 table(cut(x, breaks = y))

  (0,10]  (10,20]  (20,30]  (30,40]  (40,50]  (50,60]  (60,70]  (70,80]  (80,90] (90,100] 
      51       66       36       44       54       49       55       46       58       41
```

`findInterval` + `table` will give you the same result

```
table(findInterval(x, y,  left.open = TRUE))
```

Data

```
set.seed(505)
x <- c(sample(1:100, 500, replace = T))
y <- seq(0,100, by = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this might work:

```
x <- c(sample(1:100, 500, replace = T))
y <- seq(0,100, by = 10)

is_bigger_than <- function(y){
  data.frame(y, n = sum(x > y,na.rm = TRUE))
}
    
purrr::map_df(y,is_bigger_than)

     y   n
1    0 500
2   10 450
3   20 403
4   30 359
5   40 305
6   50 264
7   60 201
8   70 155
9   80 100
10  90  52
11 100   0
```